# Creating a library then creating a table in Base SAS

Tags: sas

My goal is to create a table in library abc using data within a remote server (i.e. my organization's data warehouse):

```
libname abc     'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/SAS';
```

The above runs successfully, and then I am able to see and access library abc on the explorer window on the left side.

Then, I submit the following:

```
proc sql;
connect to db2(database = aaa user=&user. password=&pw.);

create table abc.srv_table_1 as
select *
from srv.table_1
;
quit;
```

The creation fails and outputs the following in the log:

```
ERROR: Library abc does not exist
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure you are running the CREATE TABLE statement in the same SAS session as you ran the LIBNAME statement.  If looks funny to use `/` in a path that starts with `C:`. Windows normally uses `\ ` between directory names in a path, but I think SAS will normally fix that for you.

Comment: Show more of your code, sometimes errors are not not easily deciphered or caused from an immediately prior statement.  What SAS version and client (if using EG or Studio)

Answer (score 0):

**Libref to non-existent**

You will get a *does not exist* NOTE when a `libname` statement creates a libref to a non-existent library (i.e. folder or directory)

SQL will issue a NOTE: about stopping for errors when an invalid libref is used. Not an error that matches what you see.

```
25   libname abc 'c:\temp\abc';
NOTE: Library ABC does not exist.               <------- NOTE:, not ERROR:
26
27   proc sql;
28     create table abc.xyz as select * from sashelp.class;
29   quit;
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

[image]

Also, librefs are always uppercased by SAS, so I am not sure why your message shows both an ERROR: and a lowercase "abc".

**Missing libref (unassigned)**

You will see an ERROR:, but not the one you report seeing.

```
36   proc sql;
37     create table pqr.xyz as select * from sashelp.class;
ERROR: Libref PQR is not assigned.                              <----- ERROR:
38   quit;
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```